# Should I use/add multiple Fragments into a single ScrollView instead of ListView/RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview

In short, I need multiple components to be able to call its specific API Endpoints at a specific point of time. And those components are listed up in a scrollable parent. At first, I thought of using a RecyclerView as usual. But I'm afraid the child ViewHolders don't fit the dynamically API calling. So I come up with the idea of using some Fragments as those components, and add them into a ScrollView parent.

The layout will look like below

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_linearlayout_transparent_16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
            android:name="my.fragments.DummyChildFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
            android:name="my.fragments.DummyChildFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_3"
            android:name="my.fragments.DummyChildFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_4"
            android:name="my.fragments.DummyChildFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_5"
            android:name="my.fragments.DummyChildFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_6"
            android:name="my.fragments.DummyChildFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_8"
            android:name="my.fragments.DummyChildFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The question is what I'm trying to do is a good practice? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the flexibility of the [GetItemViewType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) method ?
You can then inflate requested item depending on you conditions...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I know about that too. But thinking of the ViewHolder will be replaced by other 'Data Object' by scrolling, but at some point, I need it to call an API, that seems to be weird.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do... Can you please add some mockup/precisions on the behavior you want ?
How are you doing your API calls ?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. So in simple, you have 10 cells in a row (where you might want to use a ListView), each is connected to a separated API endpoint and I receive GCM from server to update/call the APIs in a specific point of time for each Cell. That timestamp varies for every Cell.

Comment: Hi Nguyen. As r j detailed and as I mentioned, you should use a recyclerview and the "getItemViewType method" :)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a standard practice. Because it will take a lot of memory to load and show these many fragments at a time. As recycler view recycles views, this issue is managed by default.

If you know what kind of fragments there would be, then you can also show different views in recycler view. In the getItemViewType() method you can return the viewType according to position or the position of element from your data source.
Then in the onCreateViewHolder() you get the viewType returned from getItemViewType() method, and accordingly inflate the different layout for different views and same in the onBindViewHolder() method.

You can call the API first populate your data source and then show the recycler View.